# attendance form : delete and submit using the same form

Tags: php, database, forms, laravel

I have an attendance table which has a student_id and lesson_id columns.

in a form that has every student name beside a checkbox if the student attend this lesson the checkbox would be checked

```
@foreach ($students as $s)
                <tr>
                  <?php $sd=student::find(1)->where('id',$s->student_id)->first(); ?>
                  <?php $att=att::find(1)->where('student_id', $sd->id )->where('lesson_id', $lessonId)->first() ?>
                  <?php
                  if($att){
                    echo $att;
                    $check='checked';

                  }else {
                    $check='';

                  } ?>
                  <td>{{$sd->name}}</td>
                  <td><input {{$check}} type="checkbox" name="attend[]" value="{{$sd->id}}"></td>
                  </tr>
@endforeach
```

when i submit this form 
i want to check if there is any alter in the check boxes
such as a student has been unchecked to mark him absent.
or a student had checked which obliviously this form do the job for this part only by sending an attend array that have the id of the checked students.

Comment: Can you please clarify the problem you are having? It is difficult to tell what you are asking here.

Comment: I want a way to know if there is a checkbox has been unchecked and the value of it.